# Using cross ratios to show how an old projection technique used by artists was wrong

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space, projection, noneuclidean-geometry

[image]

These questions are taken from Stillwell's The Four Pillars of Geometry. For $Q 5.7.3$, I am confused about what the question is asking. Is at asking me to:

**1)** Compute the cross ratio's between four points $P,$ $Q,$ $R,$ $S$, where the distance $PQ=1$, $QR=e$, $RS=e^2$

**OR**

**2)** Is it asking me to compute first the cross ratio between four point $P$,$Q$,$R$,$S$ each separated by distance $1$, then compute the cross ratio for another four points $A,B,C,D$ each separated by distance $e$, and then compute the cross ratio between another 4 points $W,X,Y,Z$ each separated by distance $e^2$.

I need clarification of what is being asked of me, but I would also really appreciate some sort of dumbed down intuition (I am a complete beginner at Projective Geometry) about the technique mentioned in the question would be incorrect. Because as it stands, I really don't see how either one of **1)** or **2)** would show that the technique is incorrect? In fact, what does it even mean for the technique to be incorrect? What does it do incorrectly?

---

In response to rschwieb's answer:

What I understood from your answer:

The points on the tiles in the real world are $P=0, Q=1, R=2, S=3$. When making his drawing, the artist thinks that right way to draw this would be to have each width a constant fraction $e$ of the one before it. So on this drawing board he puts the point points $P'=0, Q'=1, R'=1+ e, S'=1+ e + e^2$. If we calculate the cross ratio of $P',Q', R', S'$, we know that it should be $\frac{4}{3}$ because the original points $P,Q,R,S$ were equally spaced. But when we calculate $\frac{(1+e)(e^2+e)}{(e)(e^2+e+1)} =\frac{4}{3}$, we get $e=0,1$, which contradicts our original assumption that $e$ was a fraction. So we conclude the technique is wrong, and doesn't correctly project the original points $P, Q, R, S$ in terms of perspective.

Comment: "The technique is incorrect" would mean it positions the lines inconsistently with the position indicated by the eye.

Comment: So for example if I have points $A=0,B=2, C=4, D=6$, and their images are $A', B', C', D'$, then 
$A'=0$, $B'= \frac{1}{k}(2)$, $C'= \frac{1}{k}(\frac{1}{k}(2)), D'= \frac{1}{k} (\frac{1}{k} (\frac{1}{k}(2)))$. Where $e=\frac{1}{k}$ is the constant they are talking about in the question. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first interpretation is fine. It's saying that along the line receding into the distance, the first gap has length $1$, the second $e$ and the third $e^2$.  The artist is succeeding in showing the gaps are shrinking, but it does not reflect reality.

The cross-ratio is a quantity for the positions of the four points, one which is invariant under projective transformations.  We know that a projective transformation can transform the line into one which has the three points equally spaced because we're supposed to assume a rectangular or square tiling.

We also know that equally spaced points always give a cross ratio of $\frac 43$, so if you compute the cross ratio of $P,Q,R,S$ as you have given, you should find it's $\frac{(1+e)^2}{1+e+e^2}$. If you equate this to $\frac43$ and solve, you should find the only solution is $e=1$, which of course isn't under consideration (we're using $e< 1$.)

You might follow up by computing, given the first gap $1$, the second gap $e$ what that third gap is in terms of $e$ for the cross-ratio to work out to $\frac43$.

---

In desmos, I plotted the artist's prediction (blue) and the cross-ratio's prediction (red) for $x$ in the interval $[0,1]$

[image]
They're close, but not the same!

---

For fun I picked the value $e=0.3$ and generated a few plots that demonstrate what the perspective looks like, when drawn that way. Keep in mind that they plot the same sequence of colored lines, just at different $y$ values.

Here's the naïve artist's formula:
[image]

And here's what projective geometry says:
[image]

With a little more work one should be able to predict the $y$ coordinate of the horizon. From what it looks like here, the artist's prediction looks like it might converge way too fast, below the true horizon.

Comment: I'm not sure how you got $\frac{(1+e)^2}{1+e+e^2}$. If I have the points $P=0, Q=1, R=e, S=e^2$, then the cross ratio $k$ is given by $k= \frac{(R-P)(S-Q)}{(R-Q)(S-P)} = \frac{(e)(e^2-1)}{(e-1)(e^2)} = \frac{e^3-e}{e^3 -e^2}$. If you equate this to $\frac 4 3$, it gives roots $e=0,1,3$.

Comment: I think I got what you're saying. Please check the edit to my question. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @user140161 You didn't assign $1, e, e^2$ to the distances between points, you assumed that the points actuallly lay at those numbers.  The coordinates for $P,Q,R,S$ would be $0, 1, 1+e, 1+e+e^2$ respectively.

Comment: @user140161 No, your edit still has the same misunderstanding I mentioned above.

Comment: AHHH, I see exactly what you mean now. Fantastic!  Thanks so much!! I was able to get $e=0, e=1$ (I got $e=0$ too because I didn't cancel out the $e's$). Other than this silly mistake with the coordinates, my logic is correct in the edit right?

Comment: @user140161 The math at the end of the post still doesn’t look right...

Comment: Fixed it. Check now

Comment: @user140161 looks good now

Comment: Let me mention a nice article: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225566365_Speculations_on_the_Origins_of_Linear_Perspective